# Bamboo Continuous Integration

Tags: build, continuous-integration, bamboo

i am new to this continuous integration tool..named Bamboo .. could someone point me to the right direction where i can get information about how to setup this bamboo .. how to write scripts for automatic deployment for different environments... thank you in advance....

Comment: Try hudson... https://hudson.dev.java.net/ It works with non-java projects too.

Comment: My project manager already decided to use the Bamboo tool ....

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you look at CruiseControl.NET? If so what are the advantages of Bamboo over CruiseControl.NET?
-- Lee

Comment: @Lee: we're moving away from CC.NET to Bamboo, because in CC.NET, you can't really scale easily. Bamboo is a central mgmt server plus any number of "build agents" - while in CC.NET, each build server is a fully functional server - no central mgmt and load balancing etc.

Comment: @marc_s that was some useful info :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will use your ant script or Mavn pom.xml to deploy and bamboo will scheduled it.

You will find a getting start tutorial here with a guide that shows you how to install Bamboo (really easy): https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-installation-guide-289276785.html

Comment: Update your answer, this link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

The set up documentation is above - as kazanaki has posted. Or search for bamboo 101 - I can't post two links in the same post apparently.

For executing scripts that you need to deploy to different environments you can use bamboo's pre-post build plug-in that can run scripts on success of build - it is available as a jar file from here:

https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/5581

It integrates with the UI so that you can specify a script pre or post the build plan running - in the configuration section of setting up your build plan.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the installation guide of bamboo official site.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-installation-guide-289276785.html

You can easily download and install bamboo. I used windows installer and it is working perfectly.

You can add a trigger for the build plan to schedule your build. Your build script might be Ant, Maven, Gradle or etc. Build script should be added to a job of your build plan. And as I said use Trigger tab to add a trigger.

For creating deployment use "Create Deployment Project" button of Stages tab of build plan. Then you can add different environments for the deployment. 
This will guide you to do it.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/tasks-for-deployment-environments-339051206.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Bamboo from the Atlassian is used to do the test on your new code commits to the repository,testing the new features as soon commit is done.

Use can use the powershell scripts to do almost anything in the bamboo plans.

Checkout the atlassian documentation for getting started.
[bamboo Documentation](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo)