# Bamboo Integration

Tags: bamboo

This is my second question on Bamboo ([My First One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403309/bamboo-continous-integration)). My understanding after reading suggested info, I need a build tool, like nAnt or MSbuild to write a script that gets the source code and builds it (I am working on a .net 3.5 with silverlight project). After, when deploying, I need to write scripts to move my files to the diff servers. Please tell me whether I am going in the right direction or not. Can I use ant, maven, bash scripts to do the same with a .net project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is true:

- Bamboo is the central management server which coordinates all work
- Bamboo itself has interfaces and plugins for lots of types of work
- Bamboo basically needs to first get your source from a source repository (lots of plugins here for a variety of systems)
- Then it needs to do the build - that can be done by using MSBuild to build your Visual Studio solution, or it could be a batch file to call your XYZ compiler and linker to create your app - whatever it is you have and use
- Once your solution or project is built, you have "artifacts" (build results, e.g. executable app, config files, etc.) lying around
- with those results, you can do additional things:

  - zip them up into a ZIP file and copy them somewhere
  - run a install builder on them and create an MSI
  - install them on a test server to make sure everything installs just fine

The sky's the limit! :-)

But in general: Bamboo is just the "orchestrator" - the coordinator. The actual work is done by either direct Bamboo plugins (of which there are plenty), or then you can call external command-line apps by means of a unix script or Windows batch file.

Marc